# SimpleXML: Get Child of Parent with Specific Attribute

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to extract get the PageViews % for 'US' only and I'm having trouble setting up the xpath for it.  Any ideas?

```
<aws:TrafficData>
<aws:DataUrl type="canonical">jobdiagnosis.com/</aws:DataUrl>
<aws:RankByCountry>
  <aws:Country Code="IN">
    <aws:Rank>54968</aws:Rank>
    <aws:Contribution>
      <aws:PageViews>0.46%</aws:PageViews>
      <aws:Users>0.46%</aws:Users>
    </aws:Contribution>
  </aws:Country>
  <aws:Country Code="US">
    <aws:Rank>703</aws:Rank>
    <aws:Contribution>
      <aws:PageViews>78.11%</aws:PageViews>
      <aws:Users>77.39%</aws:Users>
    </aws:Contribution>
  </aws:Country>
</aws:RankByCountry>
```

```
xpath('//Country[Code="US"]//PageViews')
```

Comment: Your xpath is for the default namespace only, however, the `aws:` in front of the element names shows, that the elements you're looking for are *not* in the default namespace. Therefore your xpath query will not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

All of the elements in your document are in some namespace so you need to register a prefix for that namespace URI and use that prefix in every step of your XPath expression where you refer to element names. The registered prefix doesn't have to match the one used in your document, but the namespace URI must match.

Assuming you have read the XML into variable `$xml`

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("aws", "http://that.namespace.uri");
$pageviews = $xml->xpath('//aws:Country[@Code="US"]/*/aws:PageViews');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
xpath('//Country[Code="US"]//PageViews')
```

instead of this:

```
xpath('//Country[Code="US"]//PageView')
```

**UPDATE**

try this:

```
xpath('/Country[@Code="US"]/PageViews']
```

Comment: I just caught that in my post and it was just a typo here. PageViews still returns an empty array. Thanks though.

Comment: Still getting an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

mind the namespace (aws):

```
$pageviews = $xml->xpath('//aws:Country[@Code="US"]/Contribution/PageViews');
```

Or use http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the assistance everyone, but I was still unable to get this to work using xpath. Decided to resort to looping through the 'Rank by Country' array until it found 'US'. Not ideal but it will work for my needs. Thanks again!